# Saving NSDictionary with UIImage in User defaults

Tags: ios

As the title says, I am trying to save in the User defaults an NSDictionary with some UIImages In it:

```
UIImage* img = PhotoView.image;
NSMutableDictionary *UserInfoDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
[UserInfoDictionary setObject:img forKey:@"ProfileImage"];
[UserInfoDictionary setObject:ProfileUsername.text forKey:@"Username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UserInfoDictionary forKey:@"ProfileAndFolderInformation"];
```

There may be up to 30 images added to the dictionary, but now the app crashes with the error:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
ProfileImage = "<UIImage: 0x16dc4280>";
} as an NSUserDefaults value for key ProfileAndFolderInformation
2013-11-23 21:39:00.261 Cleverly[363:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object {
ProfileImage = "<UIImage: 0x16dc4280>";
} for key ProfileAndFolderInformation'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30b59e83 0x3aeba6c7 0x30b59dc5 0x3148aa91 0xbaad9 0x33312da3 0x33312d3f 0x33312d13 0x332fe743 0x3331275b 0x33312425 0x3330d451 0x332e2d79 0x332e1569 0x30b24f1f 0x30b243e7 0x30b22bd7 0x30a8d471 0x30a8d253 0x357c12eb 0x33342845 0x9bb7d 0x3b3b3ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Is it even possible to store an image in user defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to store images directly in `NSUserDefaults`, because as the exception says, a `UIImage` is not a property list object. A property list is a combination of objects of these, and only these, classes (or subclasses thereof):

- `NSArray`
- `NSDictionary`
- `NSString`
- `NSData`
- `NSDate`
- `NSNumber`

For example, you could use `NSUserDefaults` to store an `NSArray` of `NSString` objects.

Technically, you could create a `NSData` object by converting the `UIImage` to a JPEG, PNG, or other standard file format, and then store it in NSUserDefaults, like so:

```
UIImage *image = ... ; // your image
CGFloat compressionQuality = 0.8; // the amount of compression, 1.0 being the lowest

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"key"];
```

But you really shouldn't do that. It'd probably be better to write it directly to the file system using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`:

```
UIImage *image = ... ; // your image
CGFloat compressionQuality = 0.8; // the amount of compression, 1.0 being the lowest

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality);

// Get the directories you can write to
N​S​A​r​r​a​y​ ​*​d​o​c​u​m​e​n​t​D​i​r​e​c​t​o​r​i​e​s​ ​=​ ​N​S​S​e​a​r​c​h​P​a​t​h​F​o​r​D​i​r​e​c​t​o​r​i​e​s​I​n​D​o​m​a​i​n​s​(​N​S​D​o​c​u​m​e​n​t​D​i​r​e​c​t​o​r​y​,​ N​S​U​s​e​r​D​o​m​a​i​n​M​a​s​k​, Y​E​S​)​;​
// Get the first one
​N​S​S​t​r​i​n​g​ ​*​d​o​c​u​m​e​n​t​D​i​r​e​c​t​o​r​y​ ​=​ ​[​d​o​c​u​m​e​n​t​D​i​r​e​c​t​o​r​i​e​s​ ​o​b​j​e​c​t​A​t​I​n​d​e​x​:​0​]​;​

NSString *uniqueSuffix = @"something";
NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:uniqueSuffix];

[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; // atomically is a bit safer, but slower
```

Or you could benefit from the fact that UIImage implements the NSCoding protocol:

```
@interface TestImageStore () <NSCoding>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image2;

@end

@implementation TestImageStore


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.image1 = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image1"];
        self.image2 = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image2"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.image1 forKey:@"image1"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.image2 forKey:@"image2"];
}
```

Finally, you could also use Core Data, but that is definitely more complex than the methods outlined above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize the image to disk, and then point to that file in the user defaults. `UIImage` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, so you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to serialize the image data, or you can convert the image to PNG using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and save that, but that is less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can only save a limited set of object types in `NSUserdefaults`, `UIImage` is not one of them. I am not aware of a size limit on `NSUserDefaults`. The `UIImage` could be converted to an acceptable type  but see below:

This is really abusing `NSUserDefaults`. Save data (serialized to data) in files in the documents directory, if necessary save the file names in `NSUserDefaults`. But just saving the names in NSUserDefaults is inappropriate, that is what CoreData or SQLite or other document approaches are for.

From the Apple docs:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): **NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary**. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.